# Angular 2 Set Default Form Control Value Presentation Component

Tags: angular, ngrx

I am a bit lost here.  I have an angular 2 app built with store architecture (ngrx) and using smart and presentation components.

Everything is working well in relation to store and retrieving data, but i am stuck when it comes to setting the default form control value in the presentation component.  It keeps failing to compile because the property does not exist, which is obviously a timing issue as the property is not there when it first tries to load the form.

So how to I set the default value or initial value in the form control only after the @Input() customer value is available.

**Presentation Component**

```
    import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter, ChangeDetectionStrategy} from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray, Validators, FormControl } from "@angular/forms";

// Mojito Models
import { CustomerModel } from '../../models/customer-model';

@Component({
  selector: 'mj-customer-detail',
  templateUrl: './customer-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./customer-detail.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class CustomerDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() customer: CustomerModel;
  @Output() showView: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

  customerForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {

    this.customerForm = this.fb.group({
      name: [this.customer.name, Validators.required],  // This fails to compile
      overview: ['', Validators.required],
      imagePath: ['', Validators.required]
    });

  }

}
```

**Template**

```
{{customer?.name}} **// This works fine it displays the customer name**

<form [formGroup]="customerForm"  (ngSubmit)="onSaveCustomer(contact)">

    <md-card class="demo-card demo-basic">
        <md-card-content>
            <br>
            <table style="width: 100%" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img [src]="imagePath.value" class="card-image">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <md-input-container style="width: 100%">
                            <input mdInput placeholder="Image Url" style="width: 100%" formControlName="imagePath" type="text" id="imagePath" #imagePath/>
                        </md-input-container>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <md-input-container style="width: 100%">
                <input mdInput placeholder="Name" style="width: 100%" formControlName="name" type="text" id="name" #name/>
            </md-input-container>
            <md-input-container style="width: 100%">
                <input mdInput placeholder="Overview" style="width: 100%" formControlName="overview" type="text" id="overview" #overview/>
            </md-input-container>

        </md-card-content>
    </md-card>

</form>
```

**SMART COMPONENT**

*Customer Component*

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

// 3rd Party Modules
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

// Mojito Components
import { ApplicationState } from '../../store/application-state';
import { CustomerEffects } from '../../store/effects/customers.effects';
import { ADD_CUSTOMER_SUCCESS, getCustomers, addCustomer, CustomerSelected } from '../../store/actions/customer.actions';
import { CustomerModel } from '../models/customer-model';


@Component({
  selector: 'mj-customer',
  templateUrl: './customer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./customer.component.scss']
})
export class CustomerComponent implements OnInit {

  customers$: Observable<CustomerModel>;
  customer$: Observable<CustomerModel>;
  addCustomerSuccess$ : Observable<any>;
  showView: string = 'list';

  constructor(private router: Router, private store: Store<ApplicationState>, private customerEffects : CustomerEffects) {

    this.store.dispatch(getCustomers());
    this.customers$ = store.select("customers");
    this.customer$ = store.select("customer");

    this.addCustomerSuccess$ = this.customerEffects.addCustomer$.filter(( { type } ) => type === ADD_CUSTOMER_SUCCESS);

  }

  addCustomer( customer: CustomerModel ) {

    this.store.dispatch(addCustomer(customer));

  }

  ngOnInit() {


  }

  onSelectedCustomer(selectedCustomerId){

    this.store.dispatch(CustomerSelected(selectedCustomerId));

  }

  changeView(viewType){

    this.showView = viewType;

  }

}
```

*Customer Template*

```
<mj-customer-detail (showView)="changeView($event)" [hidden]="showView!='detail'" [customer]="customer$ |async"></mj-customer-detail>
```

Comment: What's the exact error message? Where does `customer` come from? (how is it passed to the input and where did it get there)

Comment: Hi Ive added the full code for smart component as well.  Essentially i have the smart component (customer.component.ts) using ngrx store to pull data for customers array and customer object as an observable.  Then i pass the customer into the customer-detail.component as an Input().  I know this is working as when i put in {{customer?.name}} in the customer-detail.component.html it displays the customers name.

Comment: You get `customer` async, this means it's not yet available when you call `this.customerForm = this.fb.group({...`. The binding works because of `?.` which doesn't throw an exception when at first `customer` is still null`.

Answer (score 2):

Just update the form when you get the value:

```
  ngOnChanges() {
    if(this.customer) {
      this.customerForm.get('name').setValue(this.customer.name);
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.customerForm = this.fb.group({
      name: [null, Validators.required],  // This fails to compile
      overview: ['', Validators.required],
      imagePath: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }
```

Comment: Oh man - thank you so much.  I have been playing around with that for a few days.  That works great!!!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Glad to hear you could make it work :)